# Animation freezes when parsing huge object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multithreading

While I am parsing through an huge object (2000 elements), my react loading spinner freezes.

What would be the best approach to solve this apart from using a web worker?

So I have a `$.each` element which parses through and sorts the data

when I am at 100-200 elements it is fairly OK but upwards, the CSS animation starts freezing and makes it look like it sticks

```
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
//data parsing
}
```

the above freeze the thread

Someone once told me about breaking the parsing using timeouts but I can't remember the implementation nor find it on here.

I want the animation not to freeze while I am parsing the data in the background.

Comment: setTimeout wont help you either i guess. you just delay your freeze about few event loops

Comment: u want to render all this items at the same time? I would recommend you to use virtual list and show only items on viewport: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

Comment: @demkovych want the animation not to freeze while I am parsing the data in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `setTimeout` for breaking out of animations! Use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead.

Here are some useful resources:

- [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/)
- [Request Animation Frame Guide](https://flaviocopes.com/requestanimationframe/)
- https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/better-understanding-of-timers-in-javascript-settimeout-vs-requestanimationframe-bf7f99b9ff9b